# How to make a runnable jar with gradle that depends on three jars?

Tags: gradle

I have a java program with a simple main class that depends on libraries a.jar, b.jar, c.jar.
How do I make it such that I can create a runnable jar file with all those jars properly packaged?

I know in the jar task, you need to include:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin:'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.foo.bar.MainClass'
    }
}
```

But do not know what to do with the three external jars that my code uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to merge the dependency Jars into the main Jar:

```
jar {
    from "path/to/jar1", "path/to/jar2"
}
```

Or, if the Jars are retrieved from a Maven/Ivy repository:

```
jar {
    from configurations.runtime
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a plugin such as [gradle-onejar](https://github.com/akhikhl/gradle-onejar), which covers more use cases.

Comment: If from a Maven repository, how are the jars specified in your latter case?

Comment: In that case you don't specify the Jars but the configuration (see second snippet). `from configurations.runtime` is likely what you want.

Comment: I am a little confused. What you show above will pack the dependency jars into the main jar that is built by `gradle jar`, but it will not make the jar executable. For that, you need to specify the `Class-Path` too, like so: `jar {
  from configurations.runtime
  manifest { attributes (
      'Main-Class': 'com.sillydomain.AwesomeMain',
      'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "/<path>/<to>/<jars>/<in>/<production>/<environment>/$it.name" }.join(' ')  
    )
  }
}`